# Translation question on part of a lullaby

Tags: translation, particle-の, song-lyrics, particle-わ, particle-ね

I was looking for Mama's Lullaby on Youtube (Once there was a mama bear / sitting in her rocking chair etc.), and I bumped into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRgt1UQPgFo). After the astonishment that a video of an evidently Japanese song could be titled "Re: mama's lullaby", I decided to try understanding it. My tentative transcription was mostly right, but then I found the lyrics [here](http://mojim.com/twy113296x1x7.htm). I kanji-ized the part in the video as:

> いつもそばにいるの
>   あなたには見えないけど
>   いつもそばにいるの
>   思い出して　くれている時も
>
> 今日も一日
>   楽しかったわね
>   あなたが笑うと
>   ママも嬉しい

Which should mean:

> I will always be on your side
>   Even though you can't see me
>   I will always be on your side
>   Even in the times when you will remember me
>
> Today too was
>   A funny day, wasn't it?
>   If you smile
>   Mama is happy too

I have a couple of doubts:

1. Am I right in taking the の in the repeated line いつもそばにいるの as a marker of emphasis, as is an option in [sense 3 here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AE)?
2. Is my interpretation of implied subjects and objects right? This is an especially wild guess in 思い出して くれている時も.
3. Is my translation of 一日 correct?

Also, do you know where I can find a complete video of the song? Searching for the title given on mojim returns [all sorts of videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9E%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%90%E5%AE%88%E6%AD%8C), but definitely not the song here…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ending theme from anime 怪傑ゾロリ, and ゾロリ's mama has already been dead for years when the story begins, so...

1. The の is [#❷-1 in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/171157/m0u/%E3%81%AE/):

> ［終助］活用語の連体形に付く。
>   １ （下降調のイントネーションを伴って）断定の言い方を和らげる意を表す。多く、女性が使用する。

It's a sentence-ending particle. (With a falling tone) You use it to soften an assertive statement. It's more used by women.

So ゾロリ's late mama is talking/singing to him:

> I'm always by your side
>   Even though you can't see me

2. I think it means:

> I'm always by your side
>   (Of course) When you remember me, too (as well as when you're doing something else)

3. As the other poster says the 楽しい means "fun, enjoyable."

breakdown:

> 今日も today, too/again
>   一日 one day, the whole day
>   楽しかった you had fun, you enjoyed
>   わね (a feminine way of ending a sentence) ≒ ね

So I think it'd be something like:

> "(I can see that) you had another fun day today."
>   "You had fun/enjoyed the whole day today again (right?/didn't you?)"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFnlveT-v3c. It has some random subtitles (I think they're comments on the video)

1. You should probably say `be by your side` instead of `be on your side`. That said I think the `の` means more like definition 4 in Wiktionary.
2. This is pretty good. I would maybe say `think of me` instead of `will remember me`
3. There's a major problem with this part.

> 今日も一日楽しかったわね

`楽` isn't `funny`. It's means that something was fun/enjoyable, not humorous. So this sentence translates to something like: `Today was fun too, right?`

Comment: Right about the preposition. But how do I interpret the phrases if `no` is a nominalizer? `I will be always by your side, although you can't see [that I will be etc]` and `I will be … even in the times when you remember [that I will etc]`? OK for the rest.

Comment: I think that would be the English way, although it sounds very strange to say the 2nd phrase: `I will be always by your side, even when you think of me`.